# Bootstrap v 3.1.1 backdrop covers modal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

One of my sites doesn't use Twitter Bootstrap. In one page I need some Bootstrap functionality so I have included it in this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href={"stylesheets/bootstrap.css"} type="text/css" />
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I want a Bootstrap modal so I used this following code:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
                <p>You can add some text here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when the modal appears it is fade and also the page become fade and not clickable. I also cannot close the modal of the page.

I am using Bootstrap 3.1.1 and jQuery 1.7.2

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if this is the reason, but bootstrap 3.1.1 requires jquery >= 1.9.0, [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/bower.json)

Comment: I have another site where i am using the same version of jquery. It is working fine there. Different between these two sites is one is using bootstrap site wide and another just in a particular in one page

Comment: do you have a link? to check this?

Comment: Share the live link or working example where we can see the issue in action or we cant help.

Comment: @chanchal118 does your modal has a `position: fixed` or `relative`? or inside a container with this position? if so try to take it out of it

Comment: Make sure you placing the modal HTML right before closing you body tag

Comment: If Bootstrap 3.1.1 requires jQuery >= 1.9.0 I would start using the correct version, then you can try fixing your problems. Maybe if you can replicate your error in a fiddle, we can try to solve your issue. If you are not able to replicate it, then there is some previously included file which is causing problems

Comment: @chanchal118 nothing suggested worked? I thought I covered everything :)

Comment: Thanks, it helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution #1**

Change jQuery v1.7.2 to an upgraded version. See the dependencies for [bootstrap 3.1.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/bower.json):

```
{
  "name": "bootstrap",
  "version": "3.1.1",
  .
  .
  .
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">= 1.9.0"
  }
}
```

---

**Solution #2**

Check `stylesheets/bootstrap.css` is also v3.1.1. This problem can happen when js and css versions dont match.

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.1.1 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */
```

---

**Solution #3**

Bootstrap modal container and all parent elements should not have `position: fixed;` (also `relative` sometimes).

Try to take the modal out of parent containers. The best place would be just before the `</body>` closing tag.

---

**Solution #4**

Less recommended but working solution is giving negative `z-index` to the backdrop

```
.modal-backdrop {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Its a good solution when the modal is intentionally inside a fixed container. [see example](https://jsfiddle.net/5mj94v8r/1/)

Comment: For my case it was solution #3